# Webscraping via BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The following error arises - should produce a company name - any ideas based on looking to scrape the following tag:

```
<span datatype="xsd:string" property="gazorg:name">ISCA SCAFFOLD LIMITED </span>
```

from the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = requests.get('https://www.thegazette.co.uk/notice/3188283')
data.text[:1000]
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
soup.prettify()[:1000]
span = soup.find('span', {'property' : 'gazorg:name'})
company = span.text
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-4449f0e20d72> in <module>
----> 1 company = span.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`enter code here`
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Based on the error message, `company` is `None`, which means that your `soup.find(...)` isn't finding anything. Have you checked your outputs at each step to make sure you're getting what you think you should be getting?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you have not set your User-Agent. Websites may choose to give different response based on the User-Agent. Some websites may not give a valid response if the User-Agent is missing.

It is advised to set the User-Agent similar to the one you used while inspecting the site.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
}
data = requests.get('https://www.thegazette.co.uk/notice/3188283',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
span = soup.find('span', {'property' : 'gazorg:name'})
company = span.text
print(company)
```

Output

```
ISCA SCAFFOLD LIMITED
```